# Moving entity to location with pixels - libgdx - vector math

Tags: java, vector, libgdx

So I am making my bullets go to a point and travel further. Only its acting really really weird. Its like its thinking that the 0,0 location is at the top left instead of the bottom left.

This is the code:

```
float speed = 100;

    Vector2 direction;
    Vector2 thisPos = new Vector2(getX(), getY());
    Vector2 mousePos;

    public Bullet(){
        super();
        setSprite(sprite);
        setX(0); setY(0);
        float dx = Gdx.input.getX() - getX();
        float dy = Gdx.input.getY() - getY();
        mousePos = new Vector2(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY());
        direction = new Vector2(dx, dy);
        //sprite.setRotation(direction.angle(thisPos));
        direction.nor();
    }

    public void update(){
        Vector2 dirAd = new Vector2(direction);
        thisPos.x += dirAd.x * speed * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        thisPos.y += dirAd.y * speed * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        setPosition(thisPos.x, thisPos.y);
        super.update();
    }
```

I hope someone can help me what I did wrong with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gdx.input.getX() and getY() by definition do treat the top left as 0,0. From the getX() method:

"The screen origin is the top left corner."

You may need to look into the camera's unproject method, which takes the screen input coordinates and translates them to "world" space.

Comment: Yeah, but that is for the mouse coordinates. The sprite thinks the bottom left is 0,0. That must be why its acting weird. EDIT: Fixed.. just did 720 - (the rest) for the dy.